# Scrollable Inner Div inside ion content

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

Hi im trying have an inner scrolling div inside an ion content.how would i get the inner div take the remaining space rather than setting a pixel number from css.

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps!

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  
  background: #ccc;
}

input, #scroll {
  margin: 10px;
}

#scroll {
  display: flex;
  
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  background: #ddd;
  
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" placeholder="INPUT">
  <input type="text" placeholder="INPUT">
  <input type="text" placeholder="ANOTHER INPUT">
  <div id="scroll">
    <p>They see me scrolling</p>
    <p>They see me scrolling</p>
    <p>They see me scrolling</p>
    <p>They see me scrolling</p>
    <p>They see me scrolling</p>
    <p>They see me scrolling</p>
    <p>They see me scrolling</p>
    <p>They see me scrolling</p>
    <p>They see me scrolling</p>
  </div>
</div>
```